# How to return a degree in polynomial function?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am writing a program that deals with representing a polynomial as a linked list. I understand majority of how to write the code as far as the polynomial, however, I am having trouble understanding how to implement the function 'degree()' to return the highest power in a function.

For example, 
3x^2+4x+5

The function should return '2'.

Thank you!

Comment: do you mean that you want the length of the linked list minus 1?  If not, could you show what your linked list looks like?

Comment: I don't think we can help without knowing how your polynomial is represented as a list.

Comment: you need to find the max pow using the linked list? or just use the linked list for general structure of your data

Comment: how are you reading/inputing the polynomial as a string or something else?

Comment: I am inputting them as integers.

Answer (score 0):

A *polynomial* is made up of one or more *terms*.
A *term* has a base variable, an *exponent* and a *coefficient*.

```
3 x ^2  
| | |  
| | +-- Exponent  
| |  
| +---- base  
|    
+------ Coefficient
```

In representing a *term*, the base is not necessary; so only the pairs *coefficient* and *exponent* are required.

Let us implement a term as a class:

```
class Term
{
  public:
    signed int coefficient;
    signed int exponent;
};
```

Let the *sign* of the term be represented in the sign of the *coefficient* field.

A polynomial now becomes a container of `Term`:

```
typedef std::vector<Term> Polynomial;
```

Finding the term with the largest exponent now involves iterating through the container, looking at the `exponent` fields.

Inputting a polynomial is left as an exercise for the OP.
*Hint:  search the internet for "c++ polynomial" for examples.*